# request.getCookies() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

I have simple code, where I simply set a cookie in one servlet and then try to output it in another, but somehow I can't retrieve the cookie in the other page.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int life = 3600;
    Cookie para = new Cookie("para1","someValue");
    para.setMaxAge(life);
    response.addCookie(para);
    response.sendRedirect("/HelloWorld2/EndServlet");
}

//EndServlet code:


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();

    if (cookie!=null)
        for (Cookie c : cookie)
            if(c.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("para1"))
                out.println("<html><head/><body><h1>"+c.getValue()+"</h1></body></html>");
}
```

Comment: That means, that `request == null`

Comment: Is the mapping for your second servlet declared in your web.xml?

Comment: complete stack trace please because request can NEVER be null. The Servlet API is designed that way so my guess is that you are reading the trace a bit wrong.

Comment: @ginz why do you think request is null? How can I rectify it?

Comment: If the cookie needed somewehere else? If not I would not use redirection+cookies but RequestDispatcher.forward(..)+request.setAttribute.

Comment: @broncoAbierto The first servlet(HelloWorld) has two URL mappings, one in the annotation and another in the web.xml. The second's URL is not defined in the web.xml

Comment: how it is possible to write the same method 2 times? is there any change in the two doGet method signatures?

Comment: @user3163473 `NullPointerException` is throws when and only when the object, on which you're calling the method, is `null` (of course, if not explicitly `throw`n)

Comment: @Robert So using RequestDispatcher works, thanks! Do you know why sendRequest didn't seem to pass the cookie?

Comment: @user3163473, Because `sendRedirect` will clear everything you put in the response in this servlet, and therefore the response to the client will come only from the one redirected to.